# In jboss7 can we alter deployment order of multiple ears with out keeping jboss-structure.xml in ear file?

Tags: deployment, jboss

We are trying to deploy some ears into the different server versions as per clients interest, so that now i am trying to deploy our multiple ears into the jboss7, but as per deployment descriptors of jboss7,  i came to know that deployment dependency should be defined in jboss-depoyment-structure.xml and that should be placed in top deployment of ear file. But we don't want to alter the ear file.

So can any one suggest if is there any alternative way, our main target is maintaining deployment order of multiple ears and defining some common jars for all deployments.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jboss-all.xml file to configure dependencies across different EAR files. See this [tutorial](http://www.itbuzzpress.com/jboss-eap/jboss-eap-descriptors/configuring-dependencies-between-ear-files.html) for an example. 
 Hope it helps

Comment: thanx for reply, it is correct and i already know this thing, but we are trying some outer configuration where we can define the dependency like standalone.xml etc... please give suggestions in that way.

Comment: and one more thing, i think jboss-all.xml will work from jboss 7.2.X version onwards. currently we are using jboss7.1.1 final

Comment: There is no other way using JBoss AS7, so this is the answer there is.